# C# Multiple short delays without locking UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying my hand at writing a simple Snake application using blank panels and a table layout pane to form a grid. The way I decided to "form" my snake is by creating a moving "head" on my grid which changes the panel background to black. Any time a panel changes from black to white, a small (tenth of a second) delay is added. The snake grows or shrinks depending on the size of the delay.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(100 * (snake.getLength() - 1)))
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(oldColumn, oldRow).BackColor = Color.White;
                    });
```

This works fine with a smaller snake, but at larger sizes I've noticed a decrease in performance as well as background colors not being reset at times. I'm assuming this is due to the large amount of threads being created/destroyed.

Is there a way I could cut down on the amount of threads I'm using? What are some other ways I could add in a delay like this?

Comment: Games usually have an update and a render thread. The update thread runs at a fixed timestep (or can run using delta time) which performs the game logic and mutates the game state. The rendering happens seperately and draws the location of the game objects etc. I'd imagine that you probably want to store your snake "segments" in an ordered array (`List<T>`) with their position and have each one update to it's new position in the update loop. Rendering can take care of checking which panels are occupied and changing the colours.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Thread.Sleep, use Task.Delay. After that, you should use the tablLayoutPanel.Invoke to change the color, don't set it directly.

Comment: Switching over to TaskEx.Delay seems to be working much better. I'm curious though, what are the benefits of using an invoke method rather than setting the color directly?